# Highcharts, exclude data point from legend on pie chart

Tags: highcharts, legend, pie-chart

How can I exclude one specific data point from legend on pie type of chart, but show all others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That option currently does not exist in HighCharts that I can find, however, you may be able to do a little hacking of the source code to get it to work.

I used version `v2.3.3` for this hack, however, other versions may work similarly.

The code in question is around line 9336:

```
allItems = [];
    each(chart.series, function (serie) {
        var seriesOptions = serie.options;

        if (!seriesOptions.showInLegend) {
            return;
        }

        // use points or series for the legend item depending on legendType
        allItems = allItems.concat(
                serie.legendItems ||
                (seriesOptions.legendType === 'point' ?
                        serie.data :
                        serie)
        );
    });
```

Immediately after that code, place the following code:

```
for (var i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){
        if (typeof allItems[i].showInLegend !== "undefined"){
            if (!allItems[i].showInLegend){
                allItems.splice(i,1)
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then for the point set showInLegend=false like so:

```
{
    name: 'Chrome',
    y: 12.8,
    sliced: true,
    selected: true,
    showInLegend: false
},
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing the working concept: http://jsfiddle.net/mkremer90/zXSJW/

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe a good idea to mention which version of highcharts you modified.

Comment: Thanks Steve. May be awol from my pc for up to an hour, I'm wiping a HDD. Then ill check that.

Answer (score 0):

You are Looking For

```
   chart.series[0].setData()
```

Working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/XdfSd/

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fake" series, like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qaaqw/

which introduces how to display defined item in legend.

```
legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        console.log(this);
                        var thisSeriesId = this.id;
                        var thisSeriesVisibility = this.visible ? true : false;

                        $(chart.series).each(function (i, e) {

                            $(e.data).each(function(j, k){

                                if (thisSeriesId === k.id) {
                                    thisSeriesVisibility ? k.setVisible(false) : k.setVisible(true);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();

                    }
```